# Close bug if post already closed

Tags: bug

I loaded a post, there were already 4 close votes. I felt it should be migrated, so I clicked the close link to bring up the options but received a message *similar* to

> You can only open the close box every 3 seconds

I waited 5 seconds, clicked again, same issue.

I refreshed the page and realised that I was on a different SE site, so obviously whilst I was on the site reviewing the question, some one else pushed the final close vote. The message I was seeing was not an accurate description.

It's a tiny bug but a bug is a bug so thought I'd flag this!

Comment: You call it a bug, but it is more like lack of a useful enhancement. What would you suggest as a fix? Perhaps a warning banner that action has been taken (similar to what pops up in the edit review queue if you are improving on an edit and the original version is approved before you finish)?

Comment: What would I suggest as a fix? Not sure my point is clear, a fix would be a relevant message?!?